# What is the difference between a discrete set and a nowhere dense set?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

What is the difference between a discrete set and a nowhere dense set?

As far as I understand, a set $S$ is *discrete* iff for each $s \in S$ there exists an open set whose only element is $s$.  How does that differ from being nowhere dense? What are examples of sets that are discrete but not nowhere dense, or nowhere dense but not discrete?

In $\mathbb{R}$ in particular, a nowhere dense set has a closure with an empty interior.  How is that distinguished from discrete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- With discrete set you have no accumulation point.
- With dense set every point is accumulation point.

Nowhere dense lies in between these two extremes.

The examples given in wikipedia page are instructive:

For instance $S=\{\frac 1n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}\cup\{0\}$, there is one accumulation point $0$ but if you take a ball $B(0,r)$ even with $r\ll 1$ there are points inside (e.g. $\frac 1{r^2}$) which are still isolated.

Another example is $\mathbb R$ inside $\mathbb R^2$ (let assume the horizontal axis in the plane). For any point $x_0$ on the X-axis $B(x_0,r)$ contains points with $y>0$ that are therefore isolated from the X-axis.

Comment: My understanding was that ${1/n}\cup{0}$ is _not_ discrete, because every open ball around 0 contains other elements.  Isn't a set discrete only if discrete _everywhere_?

Comment: @SRobertJames Yes, zwim is giving examples of nowhere dense sets which are not discrete. The second example is really the one you should be focusing on: in the plane, the $x$-axis is highly non-discrete (e.g. it's connected) but still has empty interior (so since it's closed it's nowhere-dense).